# Quitar .HTML en URL

Tags: javascript, html5, web

buen dia, mi pagina es spotcloud.io y en las otras paginas que he agreado siempre sale el .html 
he intentado con htaccess y solo me aparece el error 404, todas las paginas estan en la misma carpeta solo los css js etc.. estan en carpetas diferente dependiendo de la pagina [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: saludos amigo que has intentado en el htaccess?

Comment: RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el sitio https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/ explica cómo hacer lo que necesitas (remover el.html).

> If you want to remove the .html extension from a html file for example
>   yoursite.com/wallpaper.html to yoursite.com/wallpaper you simply have
>   to alter the last line from the code above to match the filename:

**Traducción:** 
Si desea eliminar la extensión .html de un archivo html, por ejemplo
yoursite.com/wallpaper.html a yoursite.com/wallpaper simplemente debe modificar la última línea del código anterior para que coincida con el nombre de archivo:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Links:
http://www.htaccess-guide.com/

Comment: favor de traducir la respuesta, ayudar con contenido en otro idioma no es válido ni bien visto y puede ser causante de votos negativos, por lo demás veo bien el aporte

Comment: Gracias por el tip. Ya he modificado la respuesta.